# Running AngularJs on Django without manage.py

Tags: python, angularjs, django

I have an AngularJS project that i have to run on a django server. I have searched a lot about the problem but couldn't find any solution to it. I have an authentication page that could be authenticated through the data in the django server only. Since there is no usage of python anywhere in the project so I am unable to run it without manage.py .

Can anyone tell me how to go about it or what i am missing or anything i should know about?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the authentication system relies on data in the database which you are using Django to connect to, then there *is* usage of python in the project - to run that server and do authentication, so the Django server will have to be running, either through the `manage.py runserver` command in development or through WSGI or something similar in production.

Comment: use a node http-server if the frontend is completely independent of django.